# If R is a semilocal Dedekind domain, then R is a PID.

Tags: commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, dedekind-domain

On page 447 of *Groups, Rings, Modules*
by Maurice Auslander and David Buchsbaum:

> Proposition 1.3. For a semilocal integral domain $R$, if $M$ is a finitely generated projective $R$-module, then $M$ is a free $R$-module.
>
> Corollary 1.4. If $R$ is a semilocal Dedekind domain, then $R$ is a PID.

I understand Proposition 1.3, but couldn't understand why Proposition 1.3 implies Corollary 1.4.

Thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Dedekind domain, ideals are projective modules. So a nonzero ideal
is free in your set-up. It can't have rank $\ge2$, as then tensoring up
with the quotient field $K$ would give a $K^2$ contained in $K$. So it has
rank zero or one, and has a single generator.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate the answer.